# upload the document to notes and attachments using php toolkit salesforce

Tags: integration, php

I am trying to do the integration using PHP Toolkit and creating a record in salesforce (Custom Object).I am having an issue

Example :Let's say i have a candidate applying for the job .The Applicant needs to upload the resume and save as (Notes and attachments) with the candidate record.

Can Anyone help me on this requirement.

[image]

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<title> Creating candidate using PHP Integration for HR Application
</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
define("TOKEN_URL", "https://cs8.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token");
define("USERNAME", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
define("PASSWORD", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
define("SECURITY_TOKEN", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
require_once ('soapclient/SforcePartnerClient.php');
$mySforceConnection = new SforcePartnerClient();
$mySforceConnection->createConnection("Partner.xml");
$mySforceConnection->login(USERNAME, PASSWORD.SECURITY_TOKEN);

$params = "grant_type=password&client_id=" . CLIENT_ID
        . "&client_secret=" . CLIENT_SECRET . "&username=" . USERNAME
        . "&password=" . PASSWORD . SECURITY_TOKEN;

        //Get Access token
        $ch = curl_init(TOKEN_URL);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

        $json_response = curl_exec($ch);

        $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);

        $response = json_decode($json_response, true);
        $access_token = $response['access_token'];
        $instance_url = $response['instance_url'];
?>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="page">
        <div id="page-bgtop">
            <div id="page-bgbtm">
                <div id="content">
                    <div class="post">
                        <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="entry">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);">                          
                                </a>                            
                                <?php


                                if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                                    {
                                try {
                                    $fields = array (
                                                    'First_Name__c' => $_POST['Firstname'],
                                                    'Last_Name__c' => $_POST['Lastname'],
                                                    'Primary_contact_number__c'=>$_POST['primContactNumber'],
                                                    'Secondary_contact_number__c'=>$_POST['seoContactnumber'],
                                                    'Email__c'=> $_POST['Email'],
                                                    'How_did_you_learn_of_this_Opportunity__c'=>$_POST['HdylotOpp'],
                                                    'Please_Specify__c'=>$_POST['PleaseSpecify'],
                                                    'Status__c'=>$_POST['Status'],
                                                    'Have_you_worked_with_us_before__c'=>$_POST['Workbefore'],
                                                    'When__c'=>$_POST['When'],
                                                    'Available_to_start__c'=>$_POST['AvlToStart'],                                              
                                                    'Street_Address_1__c'=>$_POST['StreetAddress1'],
                                                    'Street_Address_2__c'=>$_POST['StreetAddress2'],
                                                    'Province__c'=>$_POST['Province'],
                                                    'City__c'=>$_POST['City'],
                                                    'Country__c'=>$_POST['Country'],
                                                    'Postal_Code__c'=>$_POST['ZIP'],
                                                    'Currently_Employed__c'=>intval($_POST['CurrentlyEmployed']),
                                                    'Current_Employer__c'=>$_POST['CurrentEmployer'],
                                                    'Start_Date_Work_Exp1__c'=>$_POST['StartDate'],
                                                    'End_Date_Work_EXP_End1__c'=>$_POST['EndDate'],
                                                    'Rate_of_Pay_1__c'=>$_POST['RateofPay'],
                                                    'Previous_Employer__c'=>$_POST['PreviousEmployer'],
                                                    'Start_Date_Prev_Work_1__c'=>$_POST['StartDate1'],
                                                    'End_Date_Prev_Wor_END_1__c'=>$_POST['EndDate1'],
                                                    'Rate_of_Pay_2__c'=>$_POST['RateofPay1'],
                                                    'Reason_for_Leaving__c'=>$_POST['ReasonforLeaving'],
                                                    'Previous_Employer_1__c'=>$_POST['PreviousEmployer1'],
                                                    'Start_Date_Prev_Work_2__c'=>$_POST['StartDate2'],
                                                    'End_Date_Prev_Wor_END_2__c'=>$_POST['EndDate2'],
                                                    'Rate_of_Pay_3__c'=>$_POST['RateofPay2'],
                                                    'Reason_for_Leaving_1__c'=>$_POST['ReasonforLeaving2'],
                                                    'Higher_Education__c'=>$_POST['HigherEducation'],
                                                    'Licenses_Certfications__c'=>$_POST['LicensesCertifications'],
                                                    'Reference_Name_1__c'=>$_POST['ReferenceName'],
                                                    'Company__c'=>$_POST['Company'],
                                                    'Relationship__c'=>$_POST['Relationship'],
                                                    'Phone_Number_1__c'=>$_POST['Phone'],
                                                    'Email_Ref_1__c'=>$_POST['Email'],
                                                    'Reference_Name_2__c'=>$_POST['ReferenceName1'],
                                                    'Company_1__c'=>$_POST['Company1'],
                                                    'Relationship_1__c'=>$_POST['Relationship1'],
                                                    'Phone_Number_2__c'=>$_POST['Phone1'],
                                                    'Email_Ref_2__c'=>$_POST['Email1'],
                                                    'Reference_Name_3__c'=>$_POST['ReferenceName2'],
                                                    'Company_3__c'=>$_POST['Company2'],
                                                    'Relationship_2__c'=>$_POST['Relationship2'],
                                                    'Phone_Number_3__c'=>$_POST['Phone2'],
                                                    'Email_Ref_3__c'=>$_POST['Email2'],

                                                    );
                                          $sObject = new SObject();
                                          $sObject->fields = $fields;
                                          $sObject->type = 'Candidate__c';
                                          echo "**** Creating the following:\r\n";
                                          $createResponse = $mySforceConnection->create(array($sObject));
                                          print_r($createResponse);
                                          } catch (Exception $e) {
                                                echo $mySforceConnection->getLastRequest();
                                                echo $e->faultstring;
                                                }

                                                //Get the record id from last insert call and use that to make attachment call
        $recordid = $createResponse[0]->id;

        $url = "$instance_url/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Attachment/";

        //Upload attachment
        if(isset($_FILES['uploaddoc']) && $_FILES['uploaddoc']!=null)
        {
            $fileName = $_FILES['uploaddoc']['name'];
            $tmpName  = $_FILES['uploaddoc']['tmp_name'];
            $fileSize = $_FILES['uploaddoc']['size'];
            $fileType = $_FILES['uploaddoc']['type'];

            if($fileSize>0)
            {
                $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
                $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
                $fileData = base64_encode($content);
                $data = array("ParentId" => "$recordid", "Name" => 'resume_' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '.pdf', "body" => "$fileData");
                $data_string = json_encode($data);
                $curl = curl_init($url);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
                array("Authorization: OAuth $access_token","Content-type: application/json"));
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);

                $json_response = curl_exec($curl);

                $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

                if ( $status != 201 ) {
                    die("Error: call to URL $url failed with status $status, response $json_response, curl_error " . curl_error($curl) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno($curl));
                }

                curl_close($curl);

                $response = json_decode($json_response, true);

                $attachmentid = $response["id"];
            }

        }

                                }       
                                ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
                <!-- end #content -->

                <!-- end #sidebar -->
                <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end #page -->
</div>
<!-- end #footer -->
</body>
</html>
```

Form:

```
    <html>
<form action="CandidateCreationPage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<Section><b> Candidate Information </b></section></br></br>
FirstName: <input type="text" name="Firstname" ></br></br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="Lastname" ></br></br>
Primary contact number :<input type="phone" name="primContactNumber" ></br></br>
Secondary contact number :<input type="phone" name="seoContactnumber" ></br></br>
Email: <input type="Email" name="Email" ></br></br>
How did you learn of this Opportunity: <select name="HdylotOpp">
                                        <option value="NONE">--NONE--</option>
                                        <option value="Kijiji">Kijiji</option>
                                        <option value="Craigslist">Craigslist</option>
                                         <option value="Indeed">Indeed</option>
                                        <option value="Workopolis">Workopolis</option>
                                         <option value="Linkedin">Linkedin</option>
                                        <option value="Trailerwizards.com">Trailerwizards.com</option>
                                         <option value="Current Employee/ Friend">Current Employee/ Friend</option>
                                        <option value="Local newspaper">Local newspaper</option>
                                        <option value="Other">Other</option>
                                        </select></br></br>
Please Specify (If Applicable): <input type="text" name="PleaseSpecify" ></br></br>
Do you want to work: <select name="Status">
                                        <option value="NONE">--NONE--</option>
                                        <option value="Full-time">Full-time</option>
                                        <option value="Part-time">Part-time</option>
                                         <option value="Summer Student/ Co-op">Summer Student/ Co-op</option>
                                        <option value="Contract">Contract</option>
                                         <option value="On Call">On Call</option>
                                        </select></br></br>
Have you worked with us before :<select name="Workbefore">
                                        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                                        <option value="No">No</option>
                                        </select></br></br>
When (If Applicable) :<input type="date" name="When" ></br></br>                                            
Avaliable to start :<input type="date" name="AvlToStart" ></br></br>


<Section><b> Address Information </b></section></br></br>                                   
Street Address 1 : <input type="text" name="StreetAddress1"></br></br>
Street Address 2 : <input type="text" name="StreetAddress2"></br></br>
State/province :<input type="Text" name="Province"></br></br>
City: <input type="text" name="City"></br></br>
Country :<input type="text" name="Country"></br></br>
Postal Code:<input type="text" name="ZIP"></br></br>

<Section><b> Work Experience </b></section></br></br>
Currently Employed? : <input type="checkbox" name="CurrentlyEmployed"></br></br>
Current Employer : <input type="text" name="CurrentEmployer"></br></br>
Start Date: <input type="date" name="StartDate"></br></br>
End Date : <input type="date" name="EndDate"></br></br>
Rate of Pay: <input type="number" min="0" max="1000000" name="RateofPay"></br></br>

Previous Employer : <input type="text" name="PreviousEmployer"></br></br>
Start Date: <input type="date" name="StartDate1"></br></br>
End Date : <input type="date" name="EndDate1"></br></br>
Rate of Pay: <input type="number" min="0" max="1000000" name="RateofPay1"></br></br>
Reason for Leaving :<textarea type="Text"  name="ReasonforLeaving"></textarea></br></br>

Previous Employer : <input type="text" name="PreviousEmployer1"></br></br>
Start Date: <input type="date" name="StartDate2"></br></br>
End Date : <input type="date" name="EndDate2"></br></br>
Rate of Pay: <input type="number" min="0" max="1000000" name="RateofPay2"></br></br>
Reason for Leaving :<textarea type="Text"  name="ReasonforLeaving2"></textarea></br></br>
<Section><b> Education /Qualifications</b></section></br></br>
Higher Education: <select name="HigherEducation">
                                        <option value="NONE">--NONE--</option>
                                        <option value="University Degree">University Degree</option>
                                        <option value="Post-Grad Degree">Post-Grad Degree</option>
                                         <option value="High School">High School</option>
                                        <option value="College Diploma">College Diploma</option>
                                         <option value="High School Diploma">High School Diploma</option>
                                        </select></br></br>
Licenses & Certifications: <select name="LicensesCertifications">
                                        <option value="NONE">--NONE--</option>
                                        <option value="Forklift License">Forklift License</option>
                                        <option value="Technician License">Technician License</option>
                                         <option value="Apprentice">Apprentice</option>
                                        <option value="Valid Driver's License">Valid Driver's License</option>
                                         <option value="First Aid Training">First Aid Training</option>
                                        </select></br></br>
<Section><b> References </b></section></br></br>

Reference Name :<input type="text" name="ReferenceName"></br></br>
Company :<input type="text" name="Company"></br></br>
Relationship :<input type="text" name="Relationship"></br></br>
Phone :<input type="phone" name="Phone"></br></br>
Email :<input type="Email" name="Email"></br></br>

Reference Name :<input type="text" name="ReferenceName1"></br></br>
Company :<input type="text" name="Company1"></br></br>
Relationship :<input type="text" name="Relationship1"></br></br>
Phone :<input type="phone" name="Phone1"></br></br>
Email :<input type="Email" name="Email1"></br></br>

Reference Name :<input type="text" name="ReferenceName2"></br></br>
Company :<input type="text" name="Company2"></br></br>
Relationship :<input type="text" name="Relationship2"></br></br>
Phone :<input type="phone" name="Phone2"></br></br>
Email :<input type="Email" name="Email2"></br></br>

Resume: <input id="breachpolicy" name="uploaddoc" class="input-file" type="file">

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>

</form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to create one app inside your salesforce as shown below

[image]

- You will get consumer secret and consumer key out of it which you will use in your code.
- Add following line inside your form

add following php code will insert attachment. I have added code from your previous question.

```
        define("CLIENT_ID", "YOURCONSUMERKEY");
        define("CLIENT_SECRET","CLIENT SECRET HERE");
        define("USERNAME", "YOUR USERNAME HERE");
        define("PASSWORD", "YOUR PASSWORD HERE");
        define("SECURITY_TOKEN", "TOKEN HERE");

        define("TOKEN_URL", "https://YOURINSTANCEURL/services/oauth2/token")

        $params = "grant_type=password&client_id=" . CLIENT_ID
        . "&client_secret=" . CLIENT_SECRET . "&username=" . USERNAME
        . "&password=" . PASSWORD . SECURITY_TOKEN;

        //Get Access token
        $ch = curl_init(TOKEN_URL);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

        $json_response = curl_exec($ch);

        $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);

        $response = json_decode($json_response, true);
        $access_token = $response['access_token'];
        $instance_url = $response['instance_url'];

        $fields = array ('First_Name__c' =>$_POST['Firstname'],'Last_Name__c' =>$_POST['Lastname'],'Mobile__c' => $_POST['Mobile']);
        $sObject = new SObject();
        $sObject->fields = $fields;
        $sObject->type = 'Candidate__c';
        echo "**** Creating the following:\r\n";
        $createResponse = $mySforceConnection->create(array($sObject));
        //Get the record id from last insert call and use that to make attachment call
        $recordid = $createResponse[0]->id;

        $url = "$instance_url/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Attachment/";

        //Upload attachment
        if(isset($_FILES['uploaddoc']) && $_FILES['uploaddoc']!=null)
        {
            $fileName = $_FILES['uploaddoc']['name'];
            $tmpName  = $_FILES['uploaddoc']['tmp_name'];
            $fileSize = $_FILES['uploaddoc']['size'];
            $fileType = $_FILES['uploaddoc']['type'];

            if($fileSize>0)
            {
                $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
                $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
                $fileData = base64_encode($content);
                $data = array("ParentId" => "$recordid", "Name" => 'resume_' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '.pdf', "body" => "$fileData");
                $data_string = json_encode($data);
                $curl = curl_init($url);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
                array("Authorization: OAuth $access_token","Content-type: application/json"));
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);

                $json_response = curl_exec($curl);

                $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

                if ( $status != 201 ) {
                    die("Error: call to URL $url failed with status $status, response $json_response, curl_error " . curl_error($curl) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno($curl));
                }

                curl_close($curl);

                $response = json_decode($json_response, true);

                $attachmentid = $response["id"];
            }

        }
```

Comment: @ himanshu I am getting the error  **Undefined variable: instance_url** when i have impleted the code above

Comment: Error in the Line ** $url = "$instance_url/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Attachment/"**

Comment: please check updated code

Comment: ..Please look in to the code .I am getting the following errors **Use of undefined constant CLIENT_ID - assumed 'CLIENT_ID'**,        **undefined constant CLIENT_SECRET - assumed 'CLIENT_SECRET**, **Undefined index: access_token**,                                                **Undefined index: instance_url**

Comment: have you completed step1 and step 2 ?

Comment: Yes, I have created the Connected App in the salesforce as you mentioned a and updated the php code (I have posted the code in the post and the connected app screen shot )

Comment: then replace CLIENT_SECRET with value from app and CLIENT_ID with consumer key

Comment: Is This the form at i Have to mentioned                                                     $params = "grant_type=password&client_id=". 3MVG9MHOv_bskkhI00957e64NfC1GuikZrCB_41_MaXPlLeJvnf . "&client_secret=" . 35255435265267772 . "&username=" . USERNAME
        . "&password=" . PASSWORD . SECURITY_TOKEN;

Comment: that is correct. we define constant variable in capital letters in PHP which you have initialised. please check updated answer.

Comment: Himanshu :The record is sucessfully created but the Attachment is not attached. I have put the Below line in my form to upload the resume(as you mentioned ) and click on submit                                                                                                        **<input id="breachpolicy" name="uploaddoc" class="input-file" type="file">**

Comment: put var_dump($response); before the $attachmentid = $response["id"]; to check what error is coming.

Comment: I am not getting any error. when i Click submit it is giving success        **Creating the following: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => a0pL0000006SFgcIAG [success] => 1 ) )**

Comment: that is record id of your custom object. i want to chekc whether notes and attachment record getting created or not. as you are novice with PHP verify every step. for instance put var_dump($response) before $access_token = $response['access_token']; to check whether you are able to connect to sfdc using api

Comment: verify $fileName value buy dumping that value using var_dump

Comment: I am getting the value for access_token and the $url too Bu t i am not getting any values for                                                                var_dump($fileName);
   var_dump($tmpName );
   var_dump($fileSize );
   var_dump($fileType); i have the problem from this line.Its is not even entering the line                                      if(isset($_FILES['uploaddoc']) && $_FILES['uploaddoc']!=null)

Comment: <input id="uploaddoc" name="uploaddoc" class="input-file" type="file"> check for this it should be inside your form tag on your page. update question with your form code as well

Comment: I have updated the question with the form code.This line of code is already present in the form       ** 
<input id="uploaddoc" name="uploaddoc" class="input-file" type="file">**

Comment: add var_dump($_FILES); before if(isset($_FILES['uploaddoc']) && $_FILES['uploaddoc']!=null)

Comment: var_dump($_FILES); =========> array(0) { }

Comment: you are missing enctype="multipart/form-data" add that in your form tag <form action="CandidateCreationPage.php" method="post">

Comment: Error:                                                                                                               **  array(0) { } **

Comment: at which line ?

Comment: var_dump($_FILES);  The same Line

Comment: have you updated your form ?

Comment: Yes.I have updated my form ..Please look at the updated from on the Question

Comment: these are the bits and pieces you need to fix. <input id="uploaddoc" name="uploaddoc" class="input-file" type="file">

Comment: go through this tutorial to understand php file upload http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/32877/php-file-upload-using-salesforce

Comment: Hi Himanshu..I dont have the chat option to reply to you

Comment: I am using XAMPP to do the php programming .How would  i turn on the  file_uploads

Comment: it's nothing to do with XAMPP it is PHP part

Comment: I have read the link that you have mentioned in w3schools.We are doing  the same right.the code seems to be good.but,i am not sure where i am making the mistake.

Comment: i found one more issue.  you are missing <body tag as well. first learn basic of html and php from that tutorial

Comment: Thank you  the attachment part worked fine.....You are the best .Thank you Very much